# Converting a function to cellfun format in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, cell

I had a matrix A(32x8) for which I wrote the following function

```
function x = y(A)
 x=[A(:,1:2),isnan(A(:,3:5)),A(:,6:end)];
 x(sum((x==1),2)>0,:) = [];
  end
```

Now I have an Array B (100x1) where each cell contains the Matrix A(32x8) with different values, So how can I write a function as same as above for all the cell in the array in MATLAB.

I tried following way

```
Class=cellfun(@(x) x{:,1:2},isnan{x{:,3:5}},x{:,6:end},B, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: C=cellfun(@(x) x(:,1:2),isnan(x(:,3:5)),x(:,6:end),B, 'UniformOutput', false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply your function `y` o each element in the cell array `B`, use `cellfun` as follows:

```
cellfun(@y, B, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

`@y` is a handle to the function you wrote. It must exist, so that if you write `y(B{1})` you get the correct output for the first element in `B`. `cellfun` simply applies that function to all elements in the cell array. It is equivalent to writing a loop over `B`.